# MySQL install from site vs Package manager/BREW MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, macos

I was wondering why would anyone want to install MySQL via something like BREW or a package manager instead of going to http://www.mysql.com/downloads/ and just downloading the entire installer?

Is there any benefits or time saving capabilities when I install my local MYSQL setup via BREW?

Comment: Any one able to shed some light here?

Answer (score 0):

Vs. using the site:

- Using brew or your package manager saves you the time (you don't have to hunt around for a download on the site).
- The site can deliver the software in one of many unpredictable ways (e.g., as anything from a script that installs things *via* your package manager or compiles from *in situ* resources), including ways that disrupt dependencies of other installed software (which is why installing via package manager is safer and why installing things in this way, *around* the package manager, should be avoided unless necessary).

Vs. your ordinary package manager:

- brew doesn't need sudo; it doesn't write new software versions over old software versions on the system or break system dependencies. Indeed, one of brew's perks is installation into user-specific directories and version-specific subdirectories. You can think of it as a more flexible, power-usery version of the package manager.
- brew can install things not packaged by your distro or newer versions of those things than are packages by your distro.
- brew is also cross-platform (works on Windows, Linux, and macOS).